# Launching same spring batch job multiple times in parallel threads .spring batch Duplicate entry 'xxxxxxx' for key 'JOB_INST_UN'

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, spring-batch

Launching same spring batch multiple times in parallel threads produces this error:

> **`.spring batch Duplicate entry 'xxxxxxx' for key 'JOB_INST_UN'`**

Here is how the jobs are called:

```
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder() .addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters(); 
JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) ApplicationContextUtils.getApplicationContext().getBean("jobLauncher"); 
Job job = (Job) ApplicationContextUtils.getApplicationContext().getBean("writeTeamsToDB"); 
try { 
    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters); 
    System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
    logger.info("thread completed.."); 
} catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

I get below error:

```
2016-06-01 11:15:17,385 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager] - <Rolling back resourceless transaction on [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager$ResourcelessTransaction@2846ce4f]>
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; 
    Duplicate entry 'writeTeamsToDB-38eb86e9d3cf1b87034c74e54d25a658' for key 'JOB_INST_UN'; 
    nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'writeTeamsToDB-38eb86e9d3cf1b87034c74e54d25a658' for key 'JOB_INST_UN'
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:239)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:645)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:866)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:927)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:932)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:115)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:135)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:125)
at com.ritsasoft.fantwiz.helper.FantwizWriteTeamsHelper.run(FantwizWriteTeamsHelper.java:39)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2016-06-01 11:15:17,388 INFO [com.ritsasoft.fantwiz.helper.FantwizWriteTeamsHelper] - <launching prediction writer.....>
2016-06-01 11:15:17,388 INFO [com.ritsasoft.fantwiz.helper.FantwizWriteTeamsHelper] - <thread for new job started..>
2016-06-01 11:15:17,388 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager] - <Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getLastJobExecution]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ>
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'writeTeamsToDB-38eb86e9d3cf1b87034c74e54d25a658' for key 'JOB_INST_UN'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2019)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1937)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1922)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:102)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:873)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:866)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:629)
... 24 more
```

What do you think I could improve / check to make it work? Is it possible for me to define the unique key myself to avoid it?

Comment: What could we do to help you? Have you read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ? Try to build an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can I please get some help on this. thanks.

Comment: thanks for reply J.Chomel. yes , i have searched on google but didn't find any solution. i use the below to launch my job,

Comment: JobParameters jobParameters = 
      new JobParametersBuilder()
      .addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
  
  JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) ApplicationContextUtils.getApplicationContext().getBean("jobLauncher");
  Job job = (Job) ApplicationContextUtils.getApplicationContext().getBean("writeTeamsToDB");
  

  try {

   JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
   System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
   logger.info("thread completed..");

  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: J.Chomel, i just added my code as a comment. I am not able to edit the question to post the code, as it is saying that the question has lot of code. sorry for that.

Comment: J.chomel, thanks for editing my question. I will make sure I follow this format next time. Thank you.

Comment: can I please get some help on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: can I please get some help on this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Well, since you seem a little lost with below error,

> `..DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)];`

I would suggest you simply remove the PK **`JOB_INST_UN`** from **`BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE`**.

Otherwise, the best person to help you might be you know... Because your question isn't accurate enough. You tell us nothing about what you tried to fix it.

Have you read or tries anything of the following?

- [Spring Batch Multi Threading - How to make each thread read unique records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087691/spring-batch-multi-threading-how-to-make-each-thread-read-unique-records)
- [How to set up multi-threading in Spring Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326695/how-to-set-up-multi-threading-in-spring-batch?rq=1)
- http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-and-java-thread-example/
- [Spring batch Multithreaded processing for Single file to Multiple FIle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672776/spring-batch-multithreaded-processing-for-single-file-to-multiple-file)

... Mentioning what you tried should gather attention to your question via links.